# PowerPC64 imports rename

Tags: binary, symbols, elf, powerpc, ida

Compiling a .c file using `powerpc64-linux-gnu-gcc` yields the following binary:

```
.text:00000000100007F4 # .rename _00000017.plt_call.memcpy__GLIBC_2.3, "_00000017.plt_call.memcpy@@GLIBC_2.3"
.text:00000000100007F4
.text:00000000100007F4 # =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00000000100007F4
.text:00000000100007F4 # void *00000017_plt_call_memcpy__GLIBC_2_3(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
.text:00000000100007F4                         _00000017.plt_call.memcpy__GLIBC_2.3:
.text:00000000100007F4 .set arg_28,  0x28
.text:00000000100007F4
.text:00000000100007F4 std       r2, arg_28(r1)
.text:00000000100007F8 ld        r12, (memcpy_plt - 0x10027F00)(r2) # memcpy
.text:00000000100007FC mtctr     r12
.text:0000000010000800 ld        r2, (qword_10020158 - 0x10027F00)(r2)
.text:0000000010000804 bctr
.text:0000000010000804 # End of function _00000017.plt_call.memcpy__GLIBC_2.3
```

I can't understand where the `.rename _00000017.plt_call.memcpy__GLIBC_2.3` comes from, and why is it renamed from just being `memcpy`?

Example to the code that gives this result:

```
int main()
{
    char* buf = (char*)calloc(25, sizeof(char));
    char* buf1 = (char*)calloc(25, sizeof(char));
    memcpy(buf, buf1, 25);
}
```

Comment: From the tags you marked this question with I assume this is the disassembly obtained from `ida`? Why use a disassembler when you have the source? Could you provide a minimal example of the source C program (which demonstrates this behaviour when compiled `with powerpc64-linux-gnu-gcc -S`)?

Comment: Yes, it's indeed disassembly from IDA. The context of my question is an automation binary analysis process I try to do. I added an example of the `.c` code, though the c code itself is not very important - just any use of `memcpy` or any other library function will lead to the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `GLIBC_2.3` stuff is introduced during linking (the compiler doesn't know anything about your Glibc version). And the `.rename` comments in the listing are an IDA artifact. (Does IDA documentation tell anything about them?)

The `@` signs you see indicate [*symbol versions*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html#VERSION), `@@` designating the default version to which external (to Glibc, in this case) references to this symbol are bound.

> The linker supports symbol versions when using ELF. Symbol versions are
>   only useful when using shared libraries.  The dynamic linker can use
>   symbol versions to select a specific version of a function when it runs
>   a program that may have been linked against an earlier version of the
>   shared library.

So the decision as to which symbol a reference in your program will be bound to is ulimately made at load time by `ld.so`. Maybe this is what `.rename` means.

With the GNU toolchain the binding decision can actually be delayed until run time. On my platform (x86_64-linux-gnu) memcpy is an *[IFUNC](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/GNU_IFUNC)*. You can check whether that's the case for you by looking at glibc's symbols like this `readelf -s /lib/libc.so.6 | grep IFUNC.*memcpy`. In theory, though, IDA  wouldn't know the ultimate destination without running the code, so ifuncs are likely irrelevant here. You can test other libc functions that are not ifuncs for the sake of a cleaner experiment though.